# not able to retrieve command line options

Tags: java, command-line

I have been trying to put my head around this. There are no errors but I am not seeing the desired answer:

```
public class Clopts {
    private static Options options = null; 

    private static final String InputDir = "i";
    private static final String OutputDir = "o";
    private String input;
    private CommandLine cmd = null; 

    static{
            options = new Options();
            options.addOption(InputDir, false, "Input Directory");
            options.addOption(OutputDir, false, "Output Directory. " + OutputDir );
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clopts cliProg = new Clopts();
        cliProg.loadArgs(args);
    }

    private void loadArgs(String[] args){
        CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
        try {
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Error parsing arguments");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (cmd.hasOption(InputDir)){
            input = cmd.getOptionValue(InputDir);
            System.out.println(input); // This is always null :(
        }
    }
}
```

While I am passing the argument `-i foo -o bar`
But I am not seeing the foo or bar every time i see is null.

Also I want to println in the main module. How do i get the options from command line and then print out what the options are.

Comment: I am using existing library.. I am using apache commons cli library?

Comment: What happens when you `System.out.println(args);`?

Comment: As per Java naming convention, you should write `private static final String INPUT_DIR = "i";`

Comment: @DanielKaplan that would print something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@13e8d89`

Comment: I meant to print the contents of it but yes, I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define your options with:

```
options.addOption(InputDir, false, "Input Directory");
options.addOption(OutputDir, false, "Output Directory. " + OutputDir );
```

The `false` means they don't take arguments. If you want an option value you must specify `true` here.

Comment: Awesome.. I thought that those flags are for optional or required fields.. ?? How do i print those  options in the main module..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, print the usage/help information?

Comment: Yes.. but also.. As of now println is in "loadArgs" method but how do i print these arguments in "main" method?

Comment: You can assign the value to a member variable and then print it from `main`